# Is it possible to remove a certain entitiy with a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map where armor stands can move towards you, and I need help with a command. Is it possible to remove a certain armor stand with a command? If it is, I need the command.

Comment: What armorstand do you want to remove? Is it one at a specific location? Or one wearing something specific? Or one named something?

Comment: @colorfusion At a specific location

Answer (score 3):

To remove an armorstand at a specific location:

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,x=XCOORD,y=YCOORD,z=ZCOORD,r=0,c=1]
```

Replace XCOORD, YCOORD and ZCOORD with its location.

Comment: Don't forget to mark @colorfusion's answer as the correct answer (faded tick under the down arrow)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is not a fixed location I would suggest executing on the player:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ kill @e[type=ArmorStand,r=5]
```

This will kill every armorstand within 5 blocks of the player

Comment: I prefer this over @SirBenet 's answer as entering coordiniates can be tedious.

Answer (score -1):

You could name the armorStand and then `/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=NAME]` (That's with a lowercase 'n')

Comment: That assumes that he gave each armor stand a distinct name.

Comment: That just killed every mob on the game.